# How to account for spaces and numbers in Caesar's cipher?

Tags: php, encryption, caesar-cipher

I am trying to encrypt a message using CAESAR'S CIPHER and the encryption also works correctly. But now I would like to know how to account for spaces and numbers in the string to be encrypted.

**PHP**

```
<?php
//the text to be encrypted
$plain_text='ABC';
 echo $plain_text."<br>";
//letters of alphabet array
$alphabet=array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 
'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');
//positions of the letters in alphabet
$flip=array_flip($alphabet);

//plaintext array
$plain_text=str_split($plain_text);
$n=count($plain_text);
$encrypted_text='';
for ($i=0; $i<$n; $i++){
    //encryption
    $encrypted_text.=$alphabet[($flip[$plain_text[$i]]+2)%26];
}

echo $encrypted_text;
?>
```

Comment: $n is a string character right?, use in_array( $n, array('1','2','3','4','5',...)); that said I would define your array of bad characters outside of the loop, then just see if it's one of them, right?

Comment: Yes $n is a string character. So where do you suggest me to use th in_array?

Comment: Well I don't know what you want to do with them, but you can find them by checking each character against an array of bad characters, so if you put an if inside the loop etc. etc..  if you want more performance you could use strpos('123456', $n) as well... http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Actually I would like to encrypt a message for example "I LOVE CODE 321" in this cipher. But for now am only being able to do "ILOVECODE".

Comment: well the obvious answer is to add them to your array of alph characters then. right.  I would change %26 mod 26 to use count of that array... though

Comment: in the alph array how to account for the space? using  '' OR ' '

Comment: you cant put ' ', in your array? a space..

Comment: Hmmm.. Thanks, I should have this common sense. My bad.

Comment: Just one more thing, I didnt get you about changing %26?

Comment: 26 the number of alpha characters is relative to the length of you alpha array.  Be easy to break ( shift cypher )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
<?php
    //the text to be encrypted
    $plain_text='ABC';
     echo $plain_text."<br>";
    //letters of alphabet array
    $alphabet=array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 
    'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',' ');
    //positions of the letters in alphabet
    $flip=array_flip($alphabet);
    $mod = count( $alphabet );

    //plaintext array
    $plain_text=str_split($plain_text);
    $n=count($plain_text);
    $encrypted_text='';
    for ($i=0; $i<$n; $i++){
        $n = strtoupper( $n );
        //encryption
        $encrypted_text.=$alphabet[($flip[$plain_text[$i]]+2) % $mod];
    }

    echo $encrypted_text;
?>
```

Add them to your list and make the $mod dynamic based on the count, I'd add strtoupper to account for lowercase letters.

That said, this isn't your homework is it?  You can put anything you like in there as long as its not a duplicate, if you want to error check for duplicates then just

```
   $alphabet = array_unique($alphabet);
```

To be sure you never put a duplicate in the array, but that might be overkill.

Comment: Nopes, it isn't, I am no computer student either. I learn scripting on my own, with stackoverflow and google and obviously from people like you.

Comment: Get a good ide like NetBeans or Eclipse PDT, that will help you a bunch.  I've been doing PHP for 7 or so years, and a lot of cryptography.

Comment: Ok. Is Laravel an IDE too??

Comment: no its a framework, an IDE is a intelligent editor with code completion etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks a tonne. :) I will definitely shift to an IDE from dreamweaver.

Comment: Yea an IDE is like having built in documentation.

Comment: During decryption should I keep $n = strtoupper( $n ); or do the lowercase thing?

Comment: You cant lower case them, if you want to handle lowercase youll have to add them to the array.  You lose that data when you upercase them and there is no way to know what it was later.  So you could add them all in and then remove the upercase, that would be the best way.  You know waht I mean there is no way to know if you upercased it or not when you decrypt it.